# Custom style in Wordpress visual editor won't apply class to link element

Tags: php, wordpress, styles, tinymce, wordpress-theming

So I have set up a custom style for the visual editor like so:

```
// Registers an editor stylesheet for the theme.
function wpdocs_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'editor-styles.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpdocs_theme_add_editor_styles' );

// Callback function to insert 'styleselect' into the $buttons array
function my_mce_buttons_2( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
// Register our callback to the appropriate filter
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'my_mce_buttons_2' );

// Callback function to filter the MCE settings
function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array ) {
    // Define the style_formats array
    $style_formats = array(
        // Each array child is a format with it's own settings
        array(
            'title' => 'Button',
            'classes' => 'button',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),
    );
    // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'
    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

    return $init_array;

}
// Attach callback to 'tiny_mce_before_init'
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init_insert_formats' );
```

**Question #1**
Why is this style not adding the "button" class to the link 'a' element? It works fine with the "inline => 'span'" argument, but applying the class directly to the link element is more clean. I don't want to litter my code with span classes.

**Question #2**
When I choose "mce_buttons_1" instead of "mce_buttons_2", the dropdown is not showing up in the first tinymce line. Can't I choose the first line because of the native dropdown?

**Question #3**
Actually I would like the custom styles to be added to the native dropdown. Is that possible? I can't find any resources on how to do that.

Thanks!
/Jeppe

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, you should first apply custom style to simple text, then add a link with link btn and editor will keep your classes.